# ETH 2 random election attack vectors?

Tags: randomness, eth-2.0

Since proof-of-stake algorithms (like ETH 2) use random sampling to choose the next validator to propose the next block, are there attack vectors with this random selection?

It seems to use [RANDAO](https://github.com/randao/randao), a DAO of users returning random numbers. Is this scalable?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand the question, but Eth 2 works this way : during an epoch `n`, each proposer signs some predetermined verifiable value which will produce a *randao reveal* ([see here](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/validator.md#randao-reveal)). The **XOR** of every randao reveal of epoch `n` is the seed of epoch `n+2`.

Once a seed is known, every validator can know which validator can propose at which slot. So this type of pseudo-randomness is subject to **last reveal attack**. It means that the last proposer of an epoch can decide whether or not to propose a block (containing her randao reveal) whether the seed favors her or not. An excellent explanation of this is done by Justin Drake [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUOBPu4W28c).